# Is there a difference between LayoutInflater.from(context) and context.getLayoutInflater()?

Tags: android, xml, layout-inflater, android-inflate

My question is basically in the title but I am curious if there is a difference between `context.getLayoutInflater()` and `LayoutInflater.from(context)`. For example:

`View contentView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.some_layout, null);`

and

`View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.some_layout, null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they do the same thing.  I see the from version used more these days, but they will do the same thing.

Comment: Is there any reason why there are two different ways of doing this same thing? Any differences in performance, or anything else worth considering?

Comment: From is actually more general-  it can inflate from any Context, not just an activity.  There are a few cases where services have a UI, its needed for them.  As for two ways to do the same thing-  there's dozens of people working on the Android SDK, sometimes both of them see the same need and add a function to fill it.